# generation of random output 3n+1 pblm

Tags: java, algorithm, error-correction

I have been trying to solve the 3n+1 question in java.However my output seems to be very random. The question is
Consider the following algorithm:

```
    1.       input n
    2.       print n
    3.       if n = 1 then STOP
    4.       if n is odd then  tex2html_wrap_inline44 
    5.       else  tex2html_wrap_inline46 
    6.       GOTO 2
```

Given the input 22, the following sequence of numbers will be printed 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1

It is conjectured that the algorithm above will terminate (when a 1 is printed) for any integral input value. Despite the simplicity of the algorithm, it is unknown whether this conjecture is true. It has been verified, however, for all integers n such that 0 < n < 1,000,000 (and, in fact, for many more numbers than this.)

Given an input n, it is possible to determine the number of numbers printed (including the 1). For a given n this is called the cycle-length of n. In the example above, the cycle length of 22 is 16.

For any two numbers i and j you are to determine the maximum cycle length over all numbers between i and j.

The Input

The input will consist of a series of pairs of integers i and j, one pair of integers per line. All integers will be less than 1,000,000 and greater than 0.

You should process all pairs of integers and for each pair determine the maximum cycle length over all integers between and including i and j.

You can assume that no operation overflows a 32-bit integer.

The Output

For each pair of input integers i and j you should output i, j, and the maximum cycle length for integers between and including i and j. These three numbers should be separated by at least one space with all three numbers on one line and with one line of output for each line of input. The integers i and j must appear in the output in the same order in which they appeared in the input and should be followed by the maximum cycle length (on the same line).
My code is as given below

```
class CC
 {
  int c,f,l,m;
  int returnCount(int i,int j)
   {
    f=0;
    for(int k=i;k<=j;k++)
     { 
       l=k;
       c=0;
       while(l>1)
        {
            if(l%2==0)
                {
                    l=l/2;
                    c++;
                }        
            else
                {
                    l=3*l+1;
                    c++;
                }

        }
       if(f<c)
        f=++c;
     }
     return f;
     }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int i,j;    
    CC obj=new CC();
  while(sc.hasNextInt())
   { 
        i=sc.nextInt();
        j=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i+" "+j+" "+obj.returnCount(i,j));
}}}
```

Now my Input is

```
605293 606510
956739 956006
826611 825983
756134 756776
478642 479101
815892 815933
719220 719135
929349 929040
```

And expected output is

```
605293 606510 341
956739 956006 352
826611 825983 313
756134 756776 362
478642 479101 338
815892 815933 269
719220 719135 274
929349 929040 339
```

However my output is

```
605293 606510 341
956739 956006 0
826611 825983 0
756134 756776 362
478642 479101 338
815892 815933 269
719220 719135 0
929349 929040 0
```

Please help me find the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your in your first line the first number is smaller than the second one, but in the second line the first number is bigger than the second one. You have to switch the numbers or find out the bigger one upfront like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CC {

    int c, f, l, m;

    int returnCount(int i, int j) {
        int smaller = Math.min(i, j);
        int bigger = Math.max(i, j);

        f = 0;
        for (int k = smaller; k <= bigger; k++) {
            l = k;
            c = 0;
            while (l > 1) {
                if (l % 2 == 0) {
                    l = l / 2;
                    c++;
                } else {
                    l = 3 * l + 1;
                    c++;
                }

            }
            if (f < c)
                f = ++c;
        }
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j;
        CC obj = new CC();
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            i = sc.nextInt();
            j = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + obj.returnCount(i, j));
        }
    }

}
```

The input and output looks then like that:

```
956739
956006
956739 956006 352
```